# What is the difference between "Hept-" and "Sept-" prefixes?

Tags: differences, latin, prefixes, greek

As I understand it, both the prefixes "Hept-" and "Sept-" are used to indicate *seven* of something.

We have examples of English words that use both:

e.g.

> Heptathalon, Heptagon, Heptane

vs

> Septuagenarian, September

I don't believe this is the case for other numbers- "Quad" is four, "Pent" is five, "Hex" is six, etc...

I believe "Sept" comes from the word "septem", which is Latin for "seven". So where has "Hept" come from? And why do no other numbers have an equivalent?

Comment: Heptember sounds too silly.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's the difference between Latin and Greek. Four, five and six do have their own forms.

Latin: bi-, tri-, quad-, quin-, sex-, sept-...
Greek: di-, tri-, tetra-, pent-, hex-, hept-...

Generally, Latin prefixes are added to Latin roots and Greek prefixes to Greek roots.

Quadrilateral, quintuplet, September etc.;
Tetrahedron, heptagon etc.

Comment: Ah, I see. But 8 is "Oct" for both, is it? (e.g. Octagenarian, Octagon)

Comment: Yes. There is some evidence that some Latin prefixes are themselves derived from Greek.

Comment: Think my confusion is because the Latin prefixes aren't used in months before September, and ages before Septuagenarian. And then eight is "Oct" for both Latin and Greek.

Comment: The example I should have thought of was "Septuplets". You _do_ get "Sextuplets", "Quintuplets", etc...

Comment: Allegedly Hexadecimal was coined even though decimal is a latin root - because someone in 50s thought sexadecimal would be rude

Comment: @mgb lol. Brilliant. That's a new question in itself.

Comment: "sexagenarian" and "pentagenarian" are both valid words though not used much.

Comment: Actually, you have those prefixes a bit wrong; you seem to have lost a final character on most of them. For example, there is no Latin *∗quad* or *∗quin* prefix; it’s actually *quadr(i)* and *quint(i)*, although the latter really should be *quinque-* more often than it is. You’re also missing letters on the Greek, which should be *mono, di, tri, tetra, penta, hexa, hepta, octa, ennea, deca, hendeca, dodeca, trideca,* etc. See [here](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57666.html) for more. PS: [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeral_prefix) does have both *quin* and *quint*.

Comment: @tchrist. The Latin prefixes are not derived from Greek, Rather the Latin, Greek, English etc. words for the numbers go back to common Indo-European.

Answer (score 5):

The Greek and Latin numeral words are **cognates**. That means they come from the same source (Lat [*co-gnatus* 'born together'](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/gen.pdf)).

In particular, they come from ***Proto-Indo-European***, the parent language (dating from around -3000) of modern European languages (excepting only Basque, Finnish, Estonian, and Hungarian).

See [this page](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/numbers.pdf) for details about the derivations of European numeral words. (You'll probably have to rotate it; it's a pdf scan in landscape mode)

Answer (score 2):

"Hept-" is from the Greek "hepta". (See, for example, the Online Etymology Dictionary entry on ["heptagon"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Heptagon&searchmode=none).)

And we do see this distinction with other numbers (though a number of Greek and Latin number terms are cognate). A tetragon, for example, is a four-sided polygon. We also speak of "pentagons" and "quintuplets".